# Creating custom errors into Stackdriver Error Reporting

Tags: google-apps-script, stackdriver

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script (GAS) add-on for spreadsheets (Google Sheets), and I would like to create entries into Stackdriver Error Reporting via code. I could see from documentation references for various other languages like C#, Java etc. but not for Google Apps Script.

Tried using console.error() and throw new Error(), both show up in Stackdriver Logging but not on Stackdriver Error Reporting module. Anybody have idea on how to create custom error entries in GAS?

Comment: Have you tried checking the ["Logging" documentation of Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging)?

Comment: Yes I did, it states "When exception logging is enabled, unhandled exceptions are automatically sent to Stackdriver Logging with a stack trace" and "Exception logging automatically integrates with Stackdriver Error Reporting, a service that aggregates and displays errors produced in your script". GAS follows this process without issues. What I'm looking for is to handle an exception (using try...catch) and pass customized error messages to Stackdriver Error Reporting.